# How to create grid/fishnet based on the cell resolution of a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion, esri-grid-format

I am interested in using water quality stations that are distributed throughout the Chesapeake Bay to attempt to explain waterbird distribution. For the sake of this question, we are only focused on Black Duck abundance, and the abundance data can be downloaded from the ebird website here [Blackduck EBird](https://science.ebird.org/en/status-and-trends/species/ambduc/downloads?regionCode=USA&week=1). I would like to create a grid or fishnet that aligns with the resolution of the raster cells. I have tried using "raster to polygon", however, I need each cell to be its an independent polygon.

Comment: What have you tried? The documentation on Create Fishnet is not brief. Note that 1) Vector is an exceedingly inefficient way to store raster data 2) This should not have anything to do with `esri-grid-format` -- GeoTIFF is the raster format of choice.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in comments by FelixIP:

1. Make sure that your map is in the same coordinate system as raster coordinate system.
2. Use **Raster to Points** geoprocessing tool to create *RasterPoints* feature
3. Use **Points to Raster** geoprocessing tool to create buffers around *RasterPoints* with where Cell Size should be reference to the original dataset
4. Use **Raster to Polygons** geoprocessing tool with Field=Value

For reference my old, slower idea:

1. Make sure that your map is in the same coordinate system as raster coordinate system.
2. Use **Raster to Points** geoprocessing tool to create *RasterPoints* feature
3. Use **Buffer** geoprocessing tool to create buffers around *RasterPoints* with Distance equal to the half of the raster cell size (resulting file *Circles*)
4. Use **Minimum Bounding Geometry** with Geometry Type = Envelope to create Polygons from *Circles*

Comment: Or just create Thiessen Polygons around the points.

Comment: After converting raster to point former table will have PointID field populated by sequential number. Convert points to raster using this field and use raster to polygon. It will work times and times faster. Of course correct snapping and raster cell size needed.